# How to sum gridview column values dynamically in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, code-behind

I have a Gridview which is sum of rows dynamically and it has delete button for each row.

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="LblSno" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" BorderWidth="1px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Particulars">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpParticulars" runat="server" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server">Total :</asp:Label>
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderWidth="1px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtAmount_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalAmount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         </FooterTemplate>
         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderWidth="1px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Record">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="delete" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" ToolTip="Delete Record" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" Text="Delete" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgAddNewRow" runat="server" CssClass="gridimage" OnClick="addnew_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/addnew.png" ToolTip="Add New Row" Text="Add Row" />
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
   <FooterStyle CssClass="header_Order" />
</asp:GridView>
```

My expected result:

```
S.No   Particulars   Amount   Edit Record
-----  -----------   ------   -----------
 1      item Cr       2500         X
 2      item Cr       1500         X
 3      item Dr       3000         X 
-----------------------------------------
        Total         7000         +
-----------------------------------------
```

Now my problem is sum of Amount for all row values while Text_Changed itself.

**WebForm1.aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub txtAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  Dim tmpval As Integer = 0
  For i As Integer = 0 To grdView1.Rows.Count - 1
     Dim TxtAmount As TextBox = DirectCast(grdView1.Rows(i).FindControl("txtAmount"), TextBox)
     Dim LblTotalAmount As Label = DirectCast(grdView1.Rows(i).FindControl("lblTotalAmount"), Label)

     tmpval = tmpval + Integer.Parse(TxtAmount.Text)
     LblTotalAmount.Text = tmpval.ToString()
  Next
End Sub
```

when cursor is out of text box, it will automatically sum the row values and bind result to footer label column. I have searched my solution in stack overflow thoroughly, but is not apt my question. So only i am asking this question.

Thanks..

Comment: What is the issue at all?

Comment: Am getting this error.... NullReferenceException was caught - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @kasin: where do you get it? Use the debugger, it is a great help to find the reason for this exception. What is `null`, the `LblTotalAmount`?

Comment: i get it from debugging only

Comment: is any other way to find solution for this problem. plz suggest me

Comment: @kasim: Tim has already given you a great hint. Where is `txtAmount` control and where are you finding your `lblTotalAmount` control?

Comment: sorry @Abhitalk.. now i have corrected my code.. then itself getting the same.

Comment: @kasim: Where are you checking that in your footer row?

Comment: sorry i could not undestand.. what i need to check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my result in another way. I created seperate table with one row to get sum of total values. Its good and working fine.

```
    S.No   Particulars   Amount   Edit Record
    -----  -----------   ------   -----------
     1      item1 Cr       2500         X
     2      item2 Cr       1500         X
     3      item3 Dr       3000         X 
    -----------------------------------------
                                        +
    -----------------------------------------
            Total          7000         
    -----------------------------------------
```

**WebForm1.aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub txtAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  Dim tmpval As Integer = 0
  Dim tmpCalVal As Integer = 0
  For i As Integer = 0 To grdView1.Rows.Count - 1
     Dim TxtAmount As TextBox = DirectCast(grdView1.Rows(i).FindControl("txtAmount"), TextBox)

     tmpCalVal = Convert.ToInt32(TxtAmount.Text)
     tmpval = tmpval + (tmpCalVal)
     lblTotalPaymentVal.Text = tmpval.ToString()
  Next
End Sub
```